# jQueryUI Dialog inside jQueryUI Tab - funny positioning

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I've got a web page using jQueryUI tabs and some of these tabs have listeners which recieve a callback when it's data is changed by another process, and offers to update the page for you with the latest data.

It's worth pointing out that the content of this tab is within an iframe.

I pop up the message using a jQueryUI dialog, but if the user has a different tab open at the time, when they return to that tab the dialog is stuck in the top left hand corner of the page:

[image]

This does not happen if the dialog pops up whilst that tab is open - it is nicely centered and remains centered even if I leave the tab and return to it later:

[image]

This is obviously something to do with the tab being hidden at the time, does anyone know of a solution?  Perhaps I'm able to reposition the dialog when the user opens that tab?  Or maybe there's some way of making it centered regardless of whether the tab is open.

Here is the dialog's code:

```
/*
show any message in a confirmation box and handle the response.
Close loading dialog if it's open otherwise
jQuery gets upset about the order of dialog creation and destruction
*/
function showConfirm(msg, confirmFunction, recordId) {
    parent.closeCustomPopup('loader');
    if(
        $j('#confirmInFrame').html(msg).dialog({
            fluid: true,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            position: { my: "center center", at: "center center", of: window },
            buttons: {
                'OK': function() {
                    $j( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                    confirmFunction(recordId);
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $j( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                }
            }
        }).dialog( 'open' )
    ){
        confirmFunction;
    }
```

In the parent page, I've tried grabbing open dialogs and repositioning them to the centre, but I'm unable to grab them (presumably because they're inside the iframe) and recieve "Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'":

```
$j('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event ,ui){
        var activeDialogs = $j('iframe:visible').contents().find('.ui-dialog:visible');
        activeDialogs.each(function(i) {
            $j(this).dialog("option", "position", { my: "center center", at: "center center", of: window });
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The default for dialog position is center center. I suspect something else is throwing it via CSS. Could you include that information in your post too or create a jsfiddle example of the issue.

Comment: It appears center center when I'm inside the tab when the dialog opens, it only does this when that tab is not the one in focus.  I think it's happening because when the tab is closed, jquery hides the tab (div) by styling to display:none, so I think when the dialog pops up inside this hidden div, it has nothing to center to.  Just an assumption though

Comment: Since you did not include HTML that was unknown. Why not just move the `<div>` out of the tab. Or create the `<div>` when `showConfirm()` is run.

Comment: the div is the tab, it is hidden when you're on another tab and is displayed when you click it's tab.  It's standard jqueryui tab behaviour

Comment: Based on the example, that is not how it looks. Please provide a proper example.